# Why am I getting different return for identical function VS code and online editor

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

When I am answering programming problems on websites, I always solve them in VS Code using a local server and the console provided with that server. Once I solve the problem, I'll paste my answer into the websites provided editor.
For this challenge, we are given a list of integfers, count and return the number of times each value appears as an array of integers

the first line contains an integer n, the number of items in arr
each of the next n lines contain an integer arr[i] where 0 <= i < n

```
100
63 25 73 1 98 73 56 84 86 57 16 83 8 25 81 56 9 53 98 67 99 12 83 89 80 91 39 86 76 85 74 39 25 90 59 10 94 32 44 3 89 30 27 79 46 96 27 32 18 21 92 69 81 40 40 34 68 78 24 87 42 69 23 41 78 22 6 90 99 89 50 30 20 1 43 3 70 95 33 46 44 9 69 48 33 60 65 16 82 67 61 32 21 79 75 75 13 87 70 33
```

```
function countingSort(arr) {
    console.log(arr.length)
    let range = arr.shift()
    const countArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        countArr.push(0)
    }
    console.log(countArr.length)
    console.log(arr.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // console.log(arr[i])
        countArr[arr[i]] += 1;
    }
    console.log(countArr)
    return countArr
}

console.log(countingSort([100,63,25,73,1,98,73,56,84,86,57,16,83,8,25,81,56,9,53,98,67,99,12,83,89,80,91,39,86,76,85,74,39,25,90,59,10,94,32,44,3,89,30,27,79,46,96,27,32,18,21,92,69,81,40,40,34,68,78,24,87,42,69,23,41,78,22,6,90,99,89,50,30,20,1,43,3,70,95,33,46,44,9,69,48,33,60,65,16,82,67,61,32,21,79,75,75,13,87,70,33]))
```

Using my local host, this solution seems to work. I submitted it and compared it to the expected output, and it's the same. However, when I submitted it on the website my output was accurate for the first 64 numbers, and then changed to NaN for the last 36 numbers.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. If anyone can point me in a direction to where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it, because it's unclear to me where the problem lies.

I've looked at the code carefully and tested it on shorter arrays and had no problem getting it to work. I also used my local server on different browsers and online JS editors, all getting the same result.

Comment: Try putting a test in the code that `arr[0] === (arr.length-1)` . If that is not true anything could happen ;-)

Comment: I was going to say that you may have `range = arr.shift()` twice, or maybe `for (let i = 0; i < arr[0]; i++) {` but then that wouldn't exactly explain the numbers - you'd get 63 results and followed by 37 mix of `undefined` or `NaN` if that were the case

Comment: what if you `const countArr = new Array(range).fill(0);` and remove that `for (let i = 0; i < range; i++) {` loop

Comment: Does the question say that the first number in the array represents the largest number from the array? If not you'll be doing `+=` on `undefined` values as `range` won't initialize the larger indices to `0`.

Comment: It seems that the first number is the length of the rest of the array, not the maximum possible number. So you'll get NaN if there are any numbers higher than this.

Comment: Yes, I edited the question and added the example input

Comment: How exactly is that challenge website calling your function? It sounds like you have to read and parse two lines of string input. Can you show us the code doing that? And link the website with its documentation?

Comment: This seems like a typical leetcode, hackerrank or similar websites problem. Where in the problem description it states, that the first value from the array is expected to contain any length? The online challenge probably provides a code template, which already does the input gathering for you and passes the final array to your `countingSort` function. Remove that `arr.shift` and just iterate `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` to handle all values. Currently you are only handling the first 64 elements of a 100 element array ...

Comment: My problem might be that I'm misunderstanding how the parameter is set up. I didn't mean to be vague, I just wasn't sure if it was okay to talk openly about specific coding challenges on popular websites. This one is hackerrank